# Convert GAE BlobInfo into a file object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

How can I convert a Google App Engine BlobInfo object into a file-like object to pass to the Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a mechanism to convert directly.

You need to open the blob with BlobReader and write it to cloudstorage.

Something like this:

```
blob_reader = BlobReader(blob_info.key())
data = blob_reader.read()
filename = '/yourbucket/your_file_filename'
with cloudstorage.open(filename, 'w') as f: 
    f.write(data)
```

Cloudstorage is the [gcs client library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052484/how-should-i-move-blobs-from-blobstore-over-to-google-cloud-storage) may be helpful if you need to migrate lots of data.